# I cloned a flutter app which has a firebase intergration with authentication using mobile number otp and storage.I am getting error while setting key

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin$ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
> > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
> > Cannot have abstract method AndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType().

https://github.com/Lakshya0257/LastMinute./tree/last_minute
This is the repository link.I need a help by clearing all my build errors

Answer (score 0):

Run
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get

1 - check your firebase dependencies are up-to-date and compatible with each other in pubspec.yaml

2 - make sure you are using compatible versions of flutter and dart